# open cv face recognition module can't say he doesn't "know" a face

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I am using open CV face recognition module in my project. when I show it a face that is found in the training data it is able to recognise the face correctly. the problem shows up when I ask it to predict a face that it never saw before. when I do that, instead of prompting that it doesn't recognise that face, it prompts one of my training data faces which is clearly wrong recognition.

Is there a way to check the accuracy of the prediction or the similarity percentage between the test fails to the trained face id?

Answer (score 0):

the open cv face recognition module allows you to adjust tolerance, which should help cut back on unknown people being recognized as training data faces, but will also marginally reduce speed.

you can pass the `tolerance` parameter to the facial recognition api when you run the recognition. It should accept values between zero and one, with  0.6  typical best performance.

```
face_recognition.api.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding_to_check, tolerance=0.6)
```

you can read more about the tolerance parameter on face-recognitions documentation [here](http://face-recognition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/face_recognition.html#face_recognition.api.compare_faces)